# Modify Date Function Based on Where Clause SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, case

Currently my case statement is based on the first day of the current month.

```
SELECT
[TicketNbr] AS 'Ticket Nbr'
-- 1st day of this month
, ( CASE  WHEN [date_entered] >=  DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())  THEN 1  ELSE 0  END) AS '1=Opened Within Last 24HR 0=No'
FROM [v_rpt_Service] WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE ([date_entered] >= '2017-04-01T11:24:00.000' AND [date_entered] < '2017-05-01T11:24:00.000')
GROUP BY [TicketNbr]
```

But I want to modify it so it will adjust so it will based on  the date range
in the where clause.  (And that can be any date ranges.)

How do I do this without variables?

Comment: use a variable?

Comment: Be careful with NOLOCK. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need variables

```
declare @startDate datetime = '2017-04-01 11:24:00'
declare @endDate datetime = '2017-05-01 11:24:00'

SELECT
[TicketNbr] AS 'Ticket Nbr'
-- 1st day of this month
, ( CASE  WHEN [date_entered] between @startDate and @endDate  THEN 1  ELSE 0  END) AS '1=Opened Within Date Range 0= No'
FROM [v_rpt_Service] WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE ([date_entered] >= startDate  AND [date_entered] < @endDate)
GROUP BY [TicketNbr]
```

Comment: Appreciate it but is there a way to do this without variables?

Comment: other than hard code it as you did in your where clause?

Comment: Correct, other than hard coding it.

Comment: @Dombey , nope. Procedures and functions and even dynamic sql would all take it hard coded or parametrized. That's almost all languages actually. I'm not sure even hypothetically how you'd do it otherwise?

Comment: How are you getting the dates in the where clause or will they be static? And is that Jan 4 and 5 or April 1 and May 1?